# AWS S3 policy based on object metadata value

Tags: amazon-s3

Is it possible to add a policy to deny/allow putting a new object based on its metadata values? I have been reading on AWS documentation but I can't find a way to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to enforce some metadata.

Details of possible policy values can be found on [Specifying Conditions in a Policy - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/amazon-s3-policy-keys.html).

However, if appears that you can use `s3:RequestObjectTagKeys` to enforce **Tags** (which are separate to Metadata).